# How can I distribute scripts that should reside in the ApplicationScriptsDirectory with my application?

Tags: swift, macos, scripting

I have an OS X application that is sandboxed (because it will be put in the App store). One of the features is that the output can be run through a translator written in ruby, python, whatever. I can execute these scripts if they are in the ApplicationScriptsDirectory and everything works fine, but I would like to include at least one of these with the application. Since the ApplicationScriptsDirectory is read only to my application, how can I distribute a couple of sample scripts that will be put in the proper place when the program is first run?

Comment: Ask the user, with an NSOpenPanel, their approval for using the ApplicationScriptsDirectory, then store the sandbox bookmark to this folder and use it to install your files.

Comment: At this point the ApplicationScriptsDirectory doesn't seem to exist. I'm guessing I should ask for access to the ~/Library/Application Scripts (the parent directory) to create mine...